# How to get the sql from a createQueryBuilder?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Do you know how I can make to get the sql from my createQueryBuilder ?

My Entity/DownloadRepository.php class:

```
 public function getLastDownload($limit)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('d');

        $query->select('l.ytId, d.title, d.date, d.id, l.creator')
            ->from('DimiYvmBundle:Log', 'l')
            ->where('d.ytId = l.ytId AND l.creator = :creator')
            ->orderBy('l.id', 'DESC')
            ->groupBy('l.ytId')
            ->setParameter('creator', 'n')
            ->setMaxResults($limit);

        // echo $query->getSQL(); => Doesn't work... 

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
```

Thanks you all for your help.
Best regards

**EDIT**

To get the sql, you have to make :

```
echo $query->getQuery()->getSql();
```

Thanks all !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get from `$query->getQuery()->getSQL()` Just keep in mind that for the parameters it will produce **?** instead of the value.
If you want to get the full SQL query with the parameters and values check the profiler tool bar in DEV mode of your page in browser.

Answer (score 7):

You need to call `getSql()` on `getQuery()` object

```
echo $query->getQuery()->getSql();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer !