# Convert SQL query to DQL doctrine query with multiple AND / OR operators

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm a developper beginner (and my first question here) and unsure of a DQL query expression vs equivalent SQL expression I want to run in database.

SQL query is :

```
SELECT *
FROM table

*[other WHERE CONDITIONS]*
WHERE (field-A = 2 AND field-B IS NULL) OR (field-A = 2 AND field-B IS NULL);
```

On the Symfony side, I'm not sure what I'm doing in terms of nesting AND / OR operators. I think that :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
*[other WHERE CONDITIONS]*
            $qb->andWhere(function ($qb, $data) {
                $qb->where(isNull('t.field-A'))
                    ->andWhere('t.field-B = :data')
                    ->orWhere('t.field-A = :data')
                    ->andWhere(isNull('t.field-B'))
                    ->setParameter('data', $data);
            });
```

Do you think my DQL query is correct compared to the SQL query ?

Thank you all for your help

Comment: This shows how you can see what SQL and doctrine query builder is building.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256005/how-to-get-the-sql-from-a-createquerybuilder

Comment: It's always tricky to use `orWhere()` in QueryBuilder. I encourage you to use `OR` condition in your `andWhere()` to facilitate lisibility. exemple: `$qb->andWhere('t.field-A IS NULL OR t.field-B = :data)`